# Wifi is disconnecting after about 1 minute

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. When I connect it for any wifi network, I have internet for about 1 minute and then the computer says that there is no internet in this network. when I'm using LAN it works fine. My wifi card is Edimax EW-7727IN. Is someone can help?

Comment: In a terminal window, `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes" /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show you the logs

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: See https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=RT2860&s=updated&type=Repositories for a newer driver.